# "Config.guess failed to determine the host type" when trying build binutils-2.7 with Cygwin

Tags: gcc, build, cygwin, osdev, binutils

I'm trying to build binutils-2.7 and gcc with Cygwin while following https://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler. Everytime I run:

```
../binutils-2.7/configure --target=i386-elf --prefix="/home/jacki" --with-sysroot --disable-nls --disable-werror
```

I get this error:

```
Config.guess failed to determine the host type.  You need to specify one.
```

I do not no much about building gcc or binutils. I'm just trying to start developing my os.